# How to solve Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' Error?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, serialization, session-state, session-storage

I wanted to config session state to be saved in a SQL Server database but while configuring it i faced this error below:

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

Although the error is self explanatory and it needs the objects to be serialized. I set the class which is going to be saved in session state as `[Serializable]` but even that i am getting the error like below:

```
[Serializable()]
    public class Cart
    {
        private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();
        public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
        {
            CartLine line = lineCollection
                .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new CartLine { Product = product, Quantity = quantity });
            }
            else
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
        }
        public void RemoveLine(Product product)
        {
            lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
        }
        public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
        {
            return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.ProductPrice * e.Quantity);
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            lineCollection.Clear();
        }
        public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
        {
            get { return lineCollection; }
        }
        public class CartLine
        {
            public Product Product { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I have implemented an interface `IModelBinder`, the second parameter `ControllerContext` has an `HttpContext` property which in turn has a `Session` property that lets me to set and get data. I can obtain the Cart object associated with the user's session by reading a value from the session data, and create a Cart if there is not one there already as like here:

```
namespace Ozhay.Web.UI.Infrastructure.Binders
{
    public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            Cart cart = null;
            if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
            }
            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart();
                if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
                    controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;
            }
            return cart;
        }
    }
}
```

So far any idea how to deal with it?
**Edit1:** Here is the configuration of the `sessionState` in the web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
      sqlConnectionString="Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = Hosay; User ID = sa, password = ******; Integrated Security=SSPI" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: did you solve the issue ?